# Nested Map function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array that I use to generate a series of options that will be populated into a html select element. This currently works fine. I've done various benchmark testing and `.map()` is the most efficient approach.

My question is, how can I group the options within an `optgroup` element. I've tried using nested `.map()` but it out puts the options ungrouped still.

**JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/57gbxrzc/**

```
const myOptsArr = [
        {
            title: 'Fruit',
            values: ['apple','pear','grapes','beer']
        },
        {
            title: 'Animals',
            values: ['apple','dog','mouse','cat']
        },
        // more here
    ];

let myOpts = `
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
  ${myOptsArr.map(item => `
        </optgroup label="${item.title}">${
        item.values.map(itemValue => `
                <option value="${itemValue}">${itemValue}</option>
            `).join('')}
        </optgroup>;
  `).join('')}
`;

document.getElementById('mySelect').innerHTML = myOpts;
```

Comment: Please describe the expected output..

Comment: you are closing this tag `</optgroup label="${item.title}">${` instead of opening it. It should be `<optgroup label="${item.title}">${`.

Comment: @PaulBota thanks! good catch. Please put it as an answer and i'll mark it as correct. Or should I just delete the question as it wasn't a logic issue?

Comment: Delete it most likely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix following problems

- `<optgroup>` not `</optgroup>`
- You don't need to `join()`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nL3szyho/)

Comment: I can't see any difference b/w OP's link and your link. The code doesn't work in your fiddle. Also create a runnable snippet on SO instead of giving external links.

Comment: @MaheerAli oh just forgot to save, thanks for pointning out updated

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error

```
</optgroup label="${item.title}">${
// change to
<optgroup ...
```